# Add a new line to a string in a row in a data frame in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I have a word its phonetic symbol, and a data frame: `word = 'come'`  `phon = '/kʌm/'` and `my_df = data.frame(matrix(, nrow = 1, ncol = 1))`. Are there ways that I can append the word and its phonetic symbol to the data frame in 2 lines?

I've tried this but it didn't work

```
word = 'come'
phon = '/kʌm/'
word_and_phon = paste0(word, phon, collapse = '\n')
my_df = data.frame(matrix(, nrow = 1, ncol = 1))
my_df[1, 1] = word_and_phon
write_xlsx(my_df, "C:\\Users\\Tuan\\Downloads\\my_df.xlsx")
```

My final goal is to export the data frame to an excel file and I don't want to manually click on each cell and press "Ctrl + Enter".

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want `my_df <- data.frame(word = word, phon = phon)`?

Comment: No, I want them to be in one cell but in 2 lines (not in 2 cells or 2 columns or 2 rows). It's like you press Ctrl+Enter in an excel cell.

Comment: `word_and_phon = paste(word, phon, sep = "\n")`

Comment: It works for me! Thanks! Do you know why it doesn't work with `paste0(word, phon, collapse = '\n')`?